# Column "path" is of type ltree but expression is of type text

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I use Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL library.
How to insert/update ltree column in PostgreSQL table via Entity Framework Core?
Database table:

```
CREATE TABLE Entity (path ltree);
```

OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("ltree");
...
entity.Property(e => e.Path).HasColumnName("path").HasColumnType("ltree");
```

Entity:

```
public string Path { get; set; }
```

And on insert i've got the error:

> Npgsql.PostgresException: 42804: column "path" is of type ltree but
>   expression is of type text

Comment: Take a look at the official documentation [link](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html). I don't think the `ltree` is officially supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Npgsql doesn't currently support the ltree type, since PostgreSQL doesn't provide a binary input/output functions for it (and Npgsql is binary-only by default). The relevant issue is https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/699.

It still is possible to read and write ltree, like other binary-unsupported types, in text mode when using the ADO.NET API - see [the Npgsql FAQ](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/faq.html) for how to do this. However, you seem to be attempting to use EF Core, where this isn't possible.

Comment: Is it possible to use it as 'text' field? Looks like some CAST should fix it, because I can read/write ltree as text in different DB management studios and can send data to ltree via ADO.NET SqlCommand

Comment: As the FAQ above says, it's possibly to both read and write as a text field, as long as you're using the ADO.NET API and not EF. Check out `AllResultTypesAreUnknown`. When writing, you can set the parameter's value to string and set NpgsqlDbType to Unknown.

Comment: Looks like it's now supported https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1592

Comment: Not yet - support for ltree has only been added at the ADO.NET layer, not in the EF Core provider.